# count number couples in big R dataset

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, counter

I have a 4049x30 dataset,every cell has a number or NA.
I need to count how many times a certain couple of numbers appear per row.
I.e.

```
m<-matrix(c(1, 2, 3,
            1, 5, 6,
            3, 5, 6,
            2, 3, 7), ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
```

I have (2,3) twice and (5,6) twice

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(col1 = str_c(m[, -ncol(m)], m[, -1])) %>% 
    count(col1) %>%
    filter(n > 1)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried launching it and this is what came out: # A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: col1 <chr>, n <int>
Warning messages:
1: In stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
2: In stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Comment: @LauraPerin do you have a `matrix` or a different object, because based on your example, it is workiing fine

Answer (score 5):

```
m_tbl <- table(paste(m[,-ncol(m)], m[,-1], sep = ','))

m_tbl[m_tbl > 1]
# 2,3 5,6 
#   2   2


m_tbl <- table(m[,-ncol(m)], m[,-1])

subset(as.data.frame(m_tbl), Freq > 1)
#    Var1 Var2 Freq
# 6     2    3    2
# 16    5    6    2


library(data.table)
m_dt <- data.table(c(m[,-ncol(m)]), c(m[,-1]))

m_dt[, .N, V1:V2][N > 1]
#    v1 v2 N
# 1:  2  3 2
# 2:  5  6 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it and it comes out 
named integer(0). could it be beacuse of all the NA?